# eclipse Galileo : how to hide/filter_out fields when doing Quick Outline (CTRL + 0)

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, hide, field, outline

I use eclipse Galileo on windows vista. How can I hide fields when doing a Quick Outline ?

In the "Outline" view, I can hide fields and do other customization;

However, in the "Quick Outline", how can I achieve the same ?

I don't want to see the fields, specifically.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the top right corner there is a down arrow button: from there you can access the filter menu of the quick outline and configure it's contents